# Open meshcat-server before code execution to improve easiness in visualization (v1.5.0)?

Tags: python, drake

I'm learning pydrake via their tutorials executing it locally in my pc (pydrake pip version). I've changed the code from [simple pendulum](https://underactuated.mit.edu/pend.html) to use Meshcat locally instead of in the notebook with:

```
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.examples.pendulum import PendulumPlant, PendulumGeometry
from pydrake.geometry import MeshcatVisualizer
from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator
from pydrake.geometry import Meshcat
import webbrowser

builder = builder.AddSystem(PendulumPlant())
scene_graph = builder.AddSystem(SceneGraph())
PendulumGeometry.AddToBuilder(builder, pendulum.get_state_output_port(), scene_graph)
meshcat = Meshcat(port=7001)
MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
meshcat.Set2dRenderMode(X_WC=RigidTransform(RotationMatrix.MakeZRotation(np.pi), [0, 1, 0]))
diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
context = simulator.get_mutable_context()
context.SetContinuousState([0.5, 0])
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
while True:
    simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 1.0)
```

But there is an inconvenience with the server (or the web page) popping up. I need to refresh each time I execute the code to be able to see the simulation. Is there a way to see the simulation automatically without the need to refresh the webpage? (version 1.5.0 of drake via pip)

I'm looking to connect like in a previous version with `meshcat-server` terminal command and later connecting it in code.
Right now I'm using the webbrowser module to open a new tab each time I execute the code, but I end up with a lot of tabs at the end of some testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/17685 underway so that the browser will automatically reconnect when the server restarts.

That will probably be an easier solution that a long-running server, though we've also considered supporting a server mode.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. Yeah, I also think it is more efficient than to use a command in the terminal.

Comment: It is worth noting that the code snippet above sets the 2D render mode. The referenced PR will not preserve that render mode. So, it may well be that the PR is only a partial solution.